# Concrete5 MVC parent::save() having trouble finding database insert function, how to save to database

Tags: php, persistence, concrete5

I am editing a concrete5 add-on and am trying to figure out how the program is saving values to the database. The following function is where the database save is happening but I am not sure where the "parent::save()" function is.

```
protected function SaveRecord() {
        $func = 'jso'.'n_encode';
        $this->errors = is_array($this->errors) ? $func($this->errors) : $this->errors;

        $this->effectiveDate = is_numeric($this->effectiveDate) ? date('Y-m-d', $this->effectiveDate) : $this->effectiveDate;
        $this->expirationDate = is_numeric($this->expirationDate) ? date('Y-m-d', $this->expirationDate) : $this->expirationDate;

        //var_dump($this); die();
        parent::Save();

        // a bit hacky, but we are saving the errors as JSON, and we might need to access them later.
        $this->errors = (array) json_decode($this->errors);
    }
```

I have followed the class up to its parent and it does not have a save function. I followed the parent up to its parent until I found a save function in the "adodb" class, but `die()` never happens when put in this function. Please help me figure out how I am supposed to save values in Concrete5 to the database! (More of my code at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940176/concrete5-add-on-extension-save-value-to-database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CaitlinHavener Your SaveRecord method should be like this.

```
public function SaveRecord($data){
    $data['my_array'] = serialize($data['my_array']);
    parent::save($data);
}
```

refer this link [concrete5 document](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/save-and-retrieve-arrays-of-data/)

Comment: but how does that save values to the database? Where is the parent::save() function?

Comment: @CaitlinHavener have you added **showTerms** field in your database table, you can add/alter table from packages/your_package/db.xml and don't forget to update your package.
Then add your **showTerms** value to $data array and save it. hope it will work, or I need to have a look to your package for more help, thanks:)

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you so much for your help! I'm Caitlinhav on skype if you want to be friends :)

Comment: @CaitlinHavener it's my pleasure, will definitely add you on skype :)

Comment: One thing to note about using the `serialize` function to save data to a field: you will want to make sure the field (`my_array` in this example) is of the type "BLOB" and *not* "TEXT". If the field type is TEXT, then data corruption could occur if non-ascii characters are saved (like curly quotes from a word doc, etc.)